# how to crossfade two layouts in android

Tags: android, android-layout, fade

I want to create a user profile like this where I have a background of person which is faded around with a mix of colors. I've made a number of user profiles but I want to learn this type. I'm unable to find any hint from the internet.

[User Profile Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n366.jpg)

I've tried something of my own to fade the images but it does not get me what

```
public class MyUser extends Fragment {
ImageView aaa;
Handler handler = new Handler();
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_user,container,false);
    aaa = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.aaa);
    (new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            for(int i=0; i<255; i++){
                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        aaa.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, i,i,i));
                    }
                });
                // next will pause the thread for some time
                try{ sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }
    }).start();
    return v;
}
```

}

I want any hint or reference for the same?

thank you in advance!

Comment: use `ObjectAnimator` / `ValueAnimator`

Comment: thanks, gonna research it for how to do that and let you know if it worked...

Comment: You can create a container having ImageView at bottom and normal faded view on the top.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/background_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_image">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/foreground_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient">

<!-- Here have the image and text view--> 
        </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

in your drawable have this gradient.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
        <gradient
            android:type="linear"
            android:startColor="#50505050"
            android:endColor="#50505050"
            android:angle="225"/>
    </shape>
```

You can get desired gradient by modifying values in gradient, This is more like a workaround to get gradient overlay effect.. to get exact layouts you need to implement accordingly